# How to find common values in groupby groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `df` of this format, my goal is to find users who participate in more than one tournament and ultimately set their 'val' value to the one they first appear with. Initially, I was thinking I need to `groupby` 'tour' but then it needs some intersection but I'm not sure how to proceed. Alternatively, I can do `pd.crosstab(df.user, df.tour)` but I'm not sure how to proceed either.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['jim','1','1', 10],['john','1','1', 12], ['jack','2', '1', 14],['jim','2','1', 10],
                           ['mel','3','2', 20],['jim','3','2', 10],['mat','4','2', 14],['nick','4','2', 20],
                          ['tim','5','3', 16],['john','5','3', 10],['lin','6','3', 16],['mick','6','3', 20]],
                   columns = ['user', 'game', 'tour', 'val'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `df` is already sorted by `tour`, we could use `groupby` + `first`:

```
df['val'] = df.groupby('user')['val'].transform('first')
```

Output:

```
    user game tour  val
0    jim    1    1   10
1   john    1    1   12
2   jack    2    1   14
3    jim    2    1   10
4    mel    3    2   20
5    jim    3    2   10
6    mat    4    2   14
7   nick    4    2   20
8    tim    5    3   16
9   john    5    3   12
10   lin    6    3   16
11  mick    6    3   20
```

Comment: Initially, I misunderstood your post. This solves the question in its entirety but the intermediate step is also of interest to me. Thank you both

Comment: @idontknowmuch I also had misunderstood your post initially and had answered what I though you wanted. So like: `df.loc[df.groupby('user')['tour'].transform('count').gt(1) & df['game'].eq('1')]` will fetch the users who played more than 1 game. You can see the edit history of my post to see other options if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` on 'user' and filter out groups with only 1 element, and then select the first one, like so:

```
df.groupby(['user']).filter(lambda g:len(g)>1).groupby('user').head(1)
```

output

```
user       game tour    val
0   jim     1   1       10
1   john    1   1       12
```

Comment: thanks, given this, I think I can work out the rest